# Extract Lines from File A that Contains Words in File B

Tags: text, bigdata, extract

I have a large text file, over `1gb` large containing data line by 
line. This is text file `A.txt`

I then have the second file, text file `B.txt` that contains 30,000 unique words 
that I want to extract from text file `A`, along with the rest of the 
line where the word is found in text file `A`.

An example of this is:

--Text File A--

```
dog in house
cat at school
kid in playground
tom at oaks
so much stuff
inhouse cool stuff
```

--Text File B--

```
house
oaks
```

--Result File Output--

```
dog in house
tom at oaks
inhouse cool stuff
```

How would I go about doing this that would work the fastest way possible? Is there any software on the market for purchase that specializes in this type of task?

I don't know any programming languages whatsoever so if anyone knows a solution that takes writing code I would need newbie instructions on how to carry it out.

I've searched for hours and hours on google in hopes to finding a solution to this but have come up with absolutely nothing meaningful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Using Java MapReduce you can do it as below:

1. Load File A in HDFS
2. Pass line by line as input to Mapper.
3. Share File B as distributed cache so is accessible by all Mappers as it is without getting divided into chunks.
4. In mapper check the input line received (from File A) for any of the words present in File B (shared as distributed cache).
5. If not found skip that line.
6. if found output the line to Reducer.
7. From Reducer write to output file.

Comment: Hi, I am a total newbie to programming and don't know any languages, including Java. Would learning what you just told me to do take someone who has no clue what you said a long time? Thanks.